# Black are on the bottom of UIViewController with an active uisearchbar after dismissing from other uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a UIviewcontroller with a table view SearchResultsController, and an active UISearchbar on it, here is a screenshot:

[image]

After I select a item from table view it opens a detail view controller like this:
[image]

But when I tap to return back, appears a black area on the bottom of the viewcontroller till the transition is finished, then it disappears, screenshot:
[image]

Here is the code how I set up the uisearchbar and uisearchcontroller:

```
UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[ADC_SEARCH_RESULTS_CONTROLLER_IDENT copy]];
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0);
[self.view insertSubview:self.searchController.searchBar belowSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
SuggestionResultsTVC *vc = (SuggestionResultsTVC *)searchResultsController.topViewController;
vc.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
self.searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: First try whether table height is causing this problem by changing the backgroundColor of viewController.

Comment: I tried, cant understand who is causing this problem.

Comment: does that black color changed to the backgroundColor you applied ?

Comment: no, that black color is not changing to the background color I applied, it remains black no matter to what parent view i am changing background.

Comment: I've NSLOG sise of uiview, and tableview before push, before dismissing, and after dismiss, and all sises are the same.

Comment: In case if you are using labels for showing that amount field check it's size and its constraints.

Comment: Try to remove auto-layout

Comment: I think this is caused by uinavigationcontroller somehow, because in the view controller where is situated uisearchbar, navigation controller hides when i activate search bar, but in detailed view controller the navigation bar is presented.
here is a link to storyboard representation:
http://s15.postimg.org/if3epivi3/Screen_Shot_2015_09_03_at_12_27_55_PM.png

Comment: Have you tried using "self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;"?